# Callback fires before fadeOut finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, callback, fadeout

I built an image gallery where Images from the DOM are clickable. Now I implemented "back" and "next" buttons, to fetch the next/prev sibling image.

Now I wanted to add a nice fadeIn/fadeOut animation for the image. The idea is to fade out the image before the src attribute is changed, do the switch, and fade the image back in so it will be changed.
Here's the code:

```
  $("section.image-view-box .icon-next").unbind('click');
  $('section.image-view-box .icon-next').click(function(){
    var currentImgObj = $('.project-load img.active-view');
    var newImgObj = currentImgObj.parent().next().children('img:only-child');
    if (newImgObj.length > 0) {

      $('section.image-view-box img').fadeOut(300, setNewViewImage(currentImgObj, newImgObj));

    }
  });

  function setNewViewImage(currentImgObj, newImgObj) {
    console.log('fired');
    $('section.image-view-box img').attr('src', newImgObj.attr('src'));
    currentImgObj.removeClass('active-view');
    newImgObj.addClass('active-view');
    setNavButtonState();
    $('section.image-view-box img').fadeIn();
  }
```

But the change of image will be during the fadeOut. That means the callback of fadeOut will be called, before the animation is finished. The console log within the callback function will output only once per click, which means, the 'section.image-view-box img' selects only the one img-tag I was expecting it to.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the callback function immediately, not referencing it to be called later.

Easiest would be to just add an anonymous function

```
$('section.image-view-box img').fadeOut(300, function() {
    setNewViewImage(currentImgObj, newImgObj);
});
```